# How to remove the button after purchase

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

Please help!!!
I am creating a screen capture application and the problem is that after clicking the PRO button and after the purchase, the ads and the button do not hide.

I am trying to remove a button and ads using layout changes:

```
setContentView (R.layout.main_pro)
the code:

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener () {
@Override
public void onIabPurchaseFinished (IabResult result, purchase purchase) {
if (result.isFailure ()) {
Log.d (TAG, "Purchase Error:" result);
return;
}
even if (purchase.getSku (). equals (SKU_REMOVE_ADS)) {
isAdsDisabled = true;
setContentView (R.layout.main_pro);
remove ads ();
Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this, “The purchase was successful,” Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show ();
}
}
};
}
Full code:

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.AdaptiveIconDrawable;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.davidgrigoryan.screenrecorder.util.Constants;
import com.davidgrigoryan.screenrecorder.util.IabHelper;
import com.davidgrigoryan.screenrecorder.util.IabResult;
import com.davidgrigoryan.screenrecorder.util.Inventory;
import com.davidgrigoryan.screenrecorder.util.Purchase;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private int mScreenDensity;
    File file;
    private Context context;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    private MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;
    private static final int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 720;
    private static final int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 1280;
    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    static final String SKU_REMOVE_ADS = "android.test.purchased";
    static final int RC_REQUEST = 10111;
    private MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_KEY = 1;
    boolean isRecording = false;
    private FloatingActionButton rec;

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    private Intent intent;
    private Activity activity;
    private boolean URL_TO_SHARE;
    private ImageView wm;
    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
    private String title;
    private String message;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private String testDeviceId;
    AdRequest adRequest;
    private AdView adView;
    IabHelper mHelper;
    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "PublicKey";
    Boolean isAdsDisabled = false;
    String payload = "Upgrade PRO";
    private Inventory i;
    private IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener;
    private static boolean isWidget = false;
    private static Context appContext;
    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView pro = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buy);
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pro.setVisibility(prefs.getBoolean("isPurchase", true) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        pro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                purchaseRemoveAds();
            }
        });
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Timer timer = new Timer();
        final TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 120000);
        adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9842509861911521/3646081879");
        AdRequest adRequestInterstitial = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice(testDeviceId)
                .build();
        AdRequest adRequestBanner = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice(testDeviceId)
                .build();
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        AdSize adSize = new AdSize(320, 50);
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-9842509861911521/3646081879");
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9842509861911521/1961271598");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Load the next interstitial.
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

        });
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        };
        if (!Service.hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_PERMISSION_KEY);
        }
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mScreenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        rec = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.rec);
        rec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onToggleScreenShare();
            }
        });
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(false);
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result, IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener) throws IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException {
                Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    return;
                }
                if (mHelper == null)
                    return;
                Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            }
        });
        queryPurchased();

        IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchasedFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
                    return;
                }
                else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_REMOVE_ADS)) {
                    isAdsDisabled = true;
                    setContentView(R.layout.main_pro);
                    removeAds();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Purchase successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
    }
    private void queryPurchased() {
        IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    // handle error here
                }
                else{
                    // does the user have the premium upgrade?
                    isAdsDisabled = inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_REMOVE_ADS);
                    // update UI accordingly
                }
            }
        };
    }
    public void purchaseRemoveAds() {
        try {

            mHelper.flagEndAsync();
            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_REMOVE_ADS, 9, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "SECURITYSTRING");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            mHelper.flagEndAsync();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.error)
                    .setMessage(R.string.error_play_store)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                    .show();
        }
        IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: "
                        + purchase);

                if (mHelper == null)
                    return;

                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    return;
                }
                if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                    return;
                }
                if (isAdsDisabled == true){
                    setContentView(R.layout.main_pro);
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

                if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_REMOVE_ADS)) {
                    removeAds();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private void removeAds() {
        adView.setEnabled(false);
        adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    public void onToggleScreenShare() {
        if (!isRecording) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.start_rec, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startService();
            initRecorder();
            shareScreen();
        } else {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Ads not loaded!");
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.stop_rec, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stopService();
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            stopScreenSharing();
        }
    }

    private void shareScreen() {
        if (mMediaProjection == null) {
            startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
        isRecording = true;
    }

    private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {
        return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("MainActivity", DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, mScreenDensity,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR, mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null, null);
    }

    private void initRecorder() {
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4); //THREE_GPP
            mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.initFile().getAbsolutePath());
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
            mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(16); // 30
            mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private File initFile() {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "ScreenRecorder");


        if (!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.wtf(TAG,
                    R.string.error_folder
                            + dir.getAbsolutePath());
            file = null;
        } else {
            file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "'VIDEO-'yyyyMMddHHmmss'.mp4'").format(new Date()));
        }
        return file;
    }

    private void stopScreenSharing() {
        if (mVirtualDisplay == null) {
            return;
        }
        mVirtualDisplay.release();
        destroyMediaProjection();
        isRecording = false;
    }


    private void destroyMediaProjection() {
        if (mMediaProjection != null) {
            mMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback);
            mMediaProjection.stop();
            mMediaProjection = null;
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "MediaProjection Stopped");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unknown request code: " + requestCode);
            return;
        }
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            isRecording = false;
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
        if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        } else
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");

        mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();
        mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);
        mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
        isRecording = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_PERMISSION_KEY: {
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] + grantResults[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    onToggleScreenShare();
                } else {
                    isRecording = false;
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), R.string.message,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction(R.string.enable,
                            new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                                    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            if (isRecording) {
                isRecording = false;
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                mMediaRecorder.reset();
            }
            mMediaProjection = null;
            stopScreenSharing();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mHelper != null)
            try {
                mHelper.dispose();
                mHelper = null;

            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
        destroyMediaProjection();
    }

    private void about() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setTitle(R.string.about);
        builder1.setMessage(R.string.description);
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.about:
                about();
                return true;
            case R.id.share:
                shareApp();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void shareApp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name));
        @SuppressLint({"StringFormatInvalid", "LocalSuppress"})
        String extraText = getString(R.string.share_desc, getString(R.string.link));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extraText);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share)));
    }

    public void startService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, Background.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", "Notification");

        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
    }

    public void stopService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, Background.class);
        stopService(serviceIntent);
    }

    boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
        String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
        return true;
    }
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You seem to only check whether the purchase is done right after the purchase, and never before. I also see two ways of handling the completed purhcase: by setting the content view, and by making something visible. To be fair, that's an awful lot of code dump to tell for certain, but it looks like you request ads regardless of whether the app is purchased, which is why your app always shows ads, it makes sense. Try reproducing the same thing with less code, make a [mcve]. Then not only will you help us help you, but most likely you'll find the error on your own while doing it.